# Android - Multiline EditText wothout auto line break

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I need to implement an EditText which allows text more than the screen size as in:

```
android:inputType="textLongMessage"
```

But also supports the Enter key as in:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Tried overriding dispatchKeyEvent but still unable to fix this.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/basicBatEdittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#000"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:hint="Hey there!\nHow is it going?"
        android:inputType="textLongMessage"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textColorHint="#fff"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />


    @Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_NEXT) {

        String temp = edittext.getText().toString() + "\n";
        edittext.setText(temp);

            return true;
        }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
};
```

It just appends two blank spaces to the EditText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textLongMessage` is a text variation (corresponding to `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_LONG_MESSAGE`), while `textMultiLine` is a flag (`TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE`), so you can theoretically  mix them :

```
  android:inputType="textMultiLine|textLongMessage"
```

I don't know why but it only works if you also set `scrollHorizontally` to true **programatically**

```
someEditText.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
```